# Canonical way to transmit protocol buffers over network?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to use Google's protocol buffers (protobuf) with Python in a networked program, using bare sockets. My question is: after the transmitting side sends a message, how does the receiving side knows what kind of message was transmitted? For example, say I have message definitions:

```
message StrMessage {
    required string str = 1;
}

message IntMessage {
    required int32 num = 1;
}
```

Now the transmitter makes a `StrMessage`, serializes it, and sends the serialized bytes over the network. How does the receiver know to deserialize the bytes with StrMessage rather than IntMessage? I've tried doing two things:

```
// Proposal 1: send one byte header to indicate type
enum MessageType {
    STR_MESSAGE = 1;
    INT_MESSAGE = 2;
}

// Proposal 2: use a wrapper message
message Packet {
    optional StrMessage m_str = 1;
    optional IntMessage m_int = 2;
}
```

Neither of these seems very clean, though, and both require me to list all the message types by hand. Is there a canonical/better way to handle this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you send varying types of messages?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams that isn't hugely uncommon... wanting to send different types of commands, for example.

Comment: @Marc: Sure, but they're all structured the same way for the most part.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams mulitple of the *same* command might be structured the same way; but *different* commands generally aren't

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been discussed before, for example [this thread on the protobuf list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/protobuf/WY77sRrt_GI/30-hPfqn9XUJ), but simply there *is* no canonical / de-facto way of doing this.

Personally, I like the `Packet` approach, as it keeps everything self-contained (and indeed, in protobuf-net I have specific methods to process data in that format, just returning the `StrMessage` / `IntMessage`, leaving the `Packet` layer as an unimportant implementation detail that never actually gets used), but since that previous proposal by Kenton never got implemented (AFAIK) it is **entirely** a matter of personal taste.

Comment: Thanks Marc! I think I'm going to go with the enum and stick a byte in front version, as the all-encompassing message approach seems to want an enum anyways for efficient parsing (according to https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#union).